# How to declare sqlConnection,sqlCommand, sqlDataAdapter and sqlDataReader with access modifiers?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, sqlclient

I'm following instructions for a project.
I'm pretty sure I followed all of the instructions, but I seem to be missing something. Maybe its the way I declared the classes, because that's exactly where the underline is. I have only encountered SQL today.

I keep getting these errors:

*Field'ClassRegistrationQuery.sqlAdapter' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Field'ClassRegistrationQuery.sqlConnect' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

The field 'ClassRegistrationQuery.sqlReader' is never used.*

Here are the instructions:

*5.Create  a  class  named ClassRegistrationQuery.  Inside  the  class,import System.Data.SqlClient, System.Data, and System.Windows.Forms See Table 2 and declare what is needed*

Now, the table indicates that the access modifier should be private for the sqlConnection, Command, DataAdapter and DataReader. The variable names were also given.

6.Go to the constructor of the class ClassRegistrationQuery. Perform the following:
a.Declare the value of the connectionString in getting the Connection String of the ClassDB.
NOTE:The connection string is located at the properties once you right-click the database file in the server explorer.

b.Initialize the SqlConnection and  call the connectionString.    Example: new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);

c.Initialize DataTable and BindingSource

7.Declare a method named DisplayList()that returns a Boolean value true.

a.Declare a string variable named ViewClubMembers and set the value by creating a query Select statement. Display only the StudentId, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Age, Gender, and Program in the ClubMembers table.

b.Instantiate the SqlAdapterand call the ViewClubMembers and sqlConnectvariables.

NOTE:Do not forget the arguments of SqlAdapter:SqlAdapter(string query, SqlConnection connect).

c.Add the following code:

i.dataTable.Clear();

ii.sqlAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

iii.bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SQLSelectInsertandUpdate{

public class ClassRegistrationQuery
{
    private SqlConnection sqlConnect;
    private SqlCommand sqlCommand;
    private SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter;
    private SqlDataReader sqlReader;

    private static string connectionString = "Data Source=MYPC;Initial Catalog = ClassDB; Integrated Security = True";

    public DataTable dataTable;
    public BindingSource bindingSource;

    public string _FirstName, _MiddlesName, _LastName, _Gender, _Program;
    public int _Age;

    SqlConnection SC = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    

    public bool DisplayList()
    {

        string ViewClubMembers = ("select StudentID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Age, Gender, Program * from ClubMemebrs");

        SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(ViewClubMembers, SC);
        dataTable.Clear();
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

        return true;

    }

    public bool RegisterStudent(int ID, long StudentID, string FirstName, string MiddleName, string LastName, int Age, string Gender, string Program)
    {
        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ClubMembers VALUES(@ID, @StudentID, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @Age, @Gender, @Program)", sqlConnect);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@RegistrationID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = StudentID;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = StudentID;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FirstName;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = MiddleName;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LastName;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Age;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Gender;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Program", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Program;

        sqlConnect.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnect.Close();

        return true;
    }


}


}
```

Comment: You have two connections 1) sqlConnect 2) SC  You configured the first one but using the 2nd one.  The 2nd is null.

Comment: @jdweng Hi, Thanks for pointing that out, but I still can't get rid of the warnings in the declarations. Could you suggest alternative ways?

Comment: This tutorial has a very fundamental error: you should not be caching the connection, adapter and reader objects as private fields, they should be regenerated every time as local variables and **disposed with `using` blocks**.